# File browser for iPad

Tags: ipad, ios, applications, file-sharing, nfs

Is there an app for the iPad that let's you view an NFS share?

It seems like [File Browser](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/filebrowser-access-files-on/id364738545?mt=8) lets you mount SMB shares and [iFiles](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ifiles/id336683524?mt=8) lets you view different cloud storage sites like Flickr and other file shares such as FTP but neither support NFS or SFTP? Is that correct?

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

[Air Sharing HD](http://avatron.com/apps/air-sharing) supports browsing SFTP (among many other protocols, but not NFS) and works well. It's the best iOS file browser I used up to now.

Answer (score 1):

try [files connect](http://www.antecea.com/apps/Files_conn/technical.html)... although its interface could be improved it works very well.

it can do: SMB, AFP, FTP, SFTP, WEBDAV not sure about NFS though.